# Obter width total do monitor usando CSS3

Tags: html, css, css3

Existe alguma forma de obter o `width` total de um monitor usando o CSS ou CSS3? Eu sei que em JS existe o `$(window).width();` que associa à uma variável a largura do tamanho do monitor.

Agora eu precisava saber se existe em CSS essa forma de obter o tamanho total do `width` pois preciso inserir essa variável no CSS.

Comment: Está usando qual pre-compilador? less? sass?

Comment: Sim e não. CSS não tem variáveis, mas dependendo do seu problema concreto pode ser possível resolver. Você pode detalhar o problema em si?

Comment: @bfavaretto preciso descobrir qual largura total da tela, para eu adicionar o valor de 50% numa animação, usando o animate CSS, tipow, a div vai fazer o bounceOutRight, eu preciso decobrir o tamanho da tela, dividir por 2 e colocar no 100% da animação essa variavel que vai receber a metade do cálculo, entende?

Comment: Em CSS não existe variável, mas você poderia obter o valor por JS e atribuir ao arquivo CSS.

Comment: @RogersCorrêa , suponhamos que minha largura seja essa:
largura = $(window).width();

ai eu preciso colocar essa qtde no css, que ficaria assim no caso:

@-webkit-keyframes bounceOutRight {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(largura); // aki a variaval
    transform: translateX(largura);// aki a variavel
  }
}

como definiria isso no js?

Comment: @RogersCorrêa , resolvi o problema, consegui colocar o valor de 100% no animate...obrigado....fim de tópico

Comment: Beleza...usou a cabeça, bombou :P

Comment: Se for possível, responda sua própria pergunta com a forma como solucionou o problema e marque-a como resolvida. O seu problema resolvido hoje pode ser útil para outros no futuro. ;)

Comment: Postei sua solução como Wiki da Comunidade, pois a pergunta não é o lugar mais adequado. Se preferir, poste como resposta sua mesmo, para poder ser votado pelos visitantes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solução postada pelo OP na pergunta:

```
@-webkit-keyframes bounceOutRight {
   0% {
      -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
      transform: translateX(0);
   }
   100% {
      -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
      transform: translateX(100%);
   }
}

@-webkit-keyframes bounceOutLeft {
   0% {
      -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
      transform: translateX(0);
   }
   100% {
      -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
      transform: translateX(-100%);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Não sei se é o caso, mas veja se "viewport-percentage lengths" serve.
Ex:

```
 div {
    width: 100vw; // 100% viewport width
    height: 100vh; // 100% viewport height
 }
```

Caso queria ler sobre o assunto: 
https://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/
https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#viewport-relative-lengths